# MySQL User Defined Function for JSON installation - can't open shared library

Tags: mysql, json

I have cloned the `LIB_MYSQLUDF_JSON` filed from github and copied the `lib_mysqludf_json.so` file into the `/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin` directory as indicated in the instructions.  When I run the command `mysql> CREATE FUNCTION json_values RETURNS STRING SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_json.so';` I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_json.so' (errno: 0 dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/lib_mysqludf_json.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find: /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/li)
```

I got no better results when I ran the `gcc -shared -o` command with respect to the `lib_mysqludf_json.so` and `lib_mysqludf_json.c` files before copying the `lib_mysqludf_json.so` file to the mysql plugin directory.

I have searched for results for the above error, which resulted in many hits, but nothing has yet indicated what might be the issue for me.

I am trying to run all this on a MacBook Pro with OS X Lion.  Any insight would be appreciated.